# I can't update wordress, plugins and upload images to media in wordpress with permissions 775 and 644

Tags: php, wordpress, file-permissions

I'm using in my Wordpress host  the follow permissions:

775 for folders
644 for files

although these is the recomended configurations, i can't update wordress, plugins and upload images to media.

I've got any others sites these permissions works normally.

Comment: Which user owns the files?

Comment: i don't understand your question.

Comment: In linux, in addition to permissions every file also has an owner account and an owner group.  That is what those numbers refer to (the first number is the owner's permissions, the second number is the group's permissions, and the third number is the permission for everyone else).  So if the files have the wrong owner having the correct permissions won't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data *
```

will solve your issues (considering that your Apache / nginx or related webserver user is www-data).

Comment: Ok. What does exactly this command do, sorry i'm don't know linux?

Comment: @Almir it changes ownership to www-data (user):www-data(group) it basically allows your apache user to perform the updates as you desire

Comment: Best to add explanation of chown cmd so OP knows what it does and understands the solution

Comment: Sure, but is it secure? will not become my site vulnerable?

Comment: @Almir nope, just set it back to your user after you've done updating :)

Answer (score 0):

Some time before I faced the same issue with my Wordpress sites. 
Solution is here:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/ -R
```

and to make this solution more secure use

```
sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www/html
```

It will fixed the issue